# Using custom classes when styling a theme in MuiTheme

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

Using the code below ([Entire Code is found here](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/master/src/styles/getMuiTheme.js)), it allows me to style all components provided in MaterialUI. However, there are instances when I need to use 2 different styles of the same component. For example, an AppBar may be green across the app while the AppBar in a dialog or Drawer may be a different color. How can I achieve this? If I attach a class to my "different" AppBar, can I use the class in this code to specify its styles? How would the syntax work?

So basically, I want these two AppBars to display differently. i.e. 1 red and 1 green

```
//no class needed on this one because it displays the default AppBar colors
<AppBar 
    title="Hulk"
/>

//A class here to identify it and modify it
<AppBar 
    className="red-header"
    title="Ironman"
/>
```

Currently, I am using a class and overwriting with !important in CSS. I don't want to do that.

```
export default function getMuiTheme(muiTheme, ...more) {
  muiTheme = merge({
      zIndex,
      isRtl: false,
      userAgent: undefined,
  }, lightBaseTheme, muiTheme, ...more);

  const {spacing, fontFamily, palette} = muiTheme;
  const baseTheme = {spacing, fontFamily, palette};

  muiTheme = merge({
    appBar: {
      color: palette.primary1Color,
      textColor: palette.alternateTextColor,
      height: spacing.desktopKeylineIncrement,
    }
}, muiTheme, {
    baseTheme, // To provide backward compatibility.
    rawTheme: baseTheme, // To provide backward compatibility.
});
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case of v0.x AppBar, you can use the `style` prop to override the inline-style of the root element, in this case Paper. You simply need to provide a backgroundColor.

If you spefically wanted to use the theme though, you can nest multiple themes:

```
const Main = () => (
  <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={myMuiTheme1}>
    <AppBar title="My AppBar 1" />
      <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={myMuiTheme2}>
        <AppBar title="My AppBar 2" />
      </MuiThemeProvider>
  </MuiThemeProvider>
);
```